# Error for routes definition on Laravel 8. Complex routes rules

Tags: laravel, routes, controller, resources, definition

Actually i'm trying to incoporate a little group of extra functions inside of a resource type controller
i have defined the actions in the controller and also defined the routes i wish to be used there:

```
1. Route::resource('/stores', StoresController::class);
2. Route::get('/stores/attributes/{store}', [StoresController::class, 'attributes'])->name('attributes.index');
3. Route::get('/stores/attributes/{store}/create/', [StoresController::class, 'attributesCreate'])->name('attributes.create');
```

first row is the common resource routes definition, behind that i'm trying to define the routes to access to a second group of function inside the StoresController. First of them (row 2) it's working properly. But every time i'm tried to access to create attributes url (row 3) i received the following message.

**Missing required parameters for [Route: attributes.create] [URI: stores/attributes/{store}/create].**

i really don't finish to understand how the routes have to be defined if this way is not correct.
i'll apreciate any hint received on this topic.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO `Missing required parameters` this error will come when you call this route function. not in `web.php`

Comment: your not providing the {store} parameter while calling attribute.create method
make sure you can pass the parameter

Comment: Thank you @RushikeshGanesh indeed i never sent the param {store} on calling sentence.